# When I compile using ndk-build with "libtensorflowlite.so" file, I faced some errors

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, ndk-build

I am beginner of TFLite.
I want to compile code based on c++ for multi-devices such as android, linux and etc. 
So, I ran my code in the local-linux and the RPI using libtensorflow.a file and successed that run this code.
I make a static library file using make file using tensorflow procject for RPI and ubuntu. 
( ./tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/build_*.sh file ), and I ran my executable code in these devices. ( I compiled use g++ and arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ )

And, I tried to build for android.
But, I faced some errors when I build for Android. 
firstly, I want to executable code in the ADB shell and target is "arm64-v8a'.
So, I built shared library( libtensorflowlite.so file ) using bazel for android.
And, I checked that ran "benchmark_model" code in my smart phone. ( this code is built using bazel from tensorflow project )
and, I built my code using ndk-build.
but I faced on some errors that are "./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libtensorflowlite.so: undefined reference to `__register_atfork@LIBC'"
Where am I making a mistake during build ?..
my code is belowed.

Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)   
    LOCAL_MODULE := tensorflowlite
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/android_64/libtensorflowlite.so
    include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)   
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += --std=c++11 -fPIC -funsafe-math-optimizations -ftree-vectorize -pie -lstdc++ -lpthread  -lrt -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/include    
    LOCAL_MODULE := MyCode
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cc
    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += tensorflowlite    
    include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Application.mk :

```
    APP_STL := c++_static
```

main code :
   this is very simple code. ( just some preprocessing for my project, and run interpreter using tflite )

include path :
   tensorflow's header file and flatbuffer's header file

Faced error during build using ndk-build :

```
$~/:$ ndk-build APP_ABI=arm64-v8a 

Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-16
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : MyCode <= main.cc
[arm64-v8a] Prebuilt       : libtensorflowlite.so <= jni/lib/android_64/
[arm64-v8a] Executable     : MyCode
./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libtensorflowlite.so: undefined reference to `__register_atfork@LIBC'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I check "libtensorflowlite.so" file using "file" and "readelf" commands in the ubuntu that is my local PC.

```
$~/: file lib/android_64/libtensorflowlite.so
libtensorflowlite.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

$~/: readelf --dynamic lib/android_64/libtensorflowlite.so
Dynamic section at offset 0x2202b8 contains 32 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libtensorflowlite.so]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [$ORIGIN/:$ORIGIN/..]
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x22cb60
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       536 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x22cd78
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       16 (bytes)
...
```

I need to your help. thanks.

Comment: I'd be wary of combining tool chains like you are doing. I'd recommend using the  precompiled AAR if you are using Android or building the AAR with the bazel build we provide. The makefile is a best effort provision that we mainly have for SOCs like Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for reading.
I solved this errors.
this is just version mismatch for android.
tflite.so file was compiled from ANDROID-26.
But, When my code was compiled, compiler's target is ANDROID-18. 
because, I didn't target setting in Application.mk file.
So, The "NDK-build" choice default setting that is ANDROID-18.
So, My executable code and so file were mismatching.